# Asp.net bootstrap modal popup not working correctly

Tags: asp.net, modalpopup

I'm trying to use asp.net grid row button for modal popup, its working for alert but cant call modal popup , how can i fix it?

```
<div id="confirm" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-body">
    Are you sure?
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" id="delete">Delete</button>
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnDeletes" ToolTip="Delete" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" OnClick="btnDelete_Click1" OnClientClick="test();"
                                                                CssClass="GridDeletebtn" runat="server" />
```

---

```
<script>
function test() 
{
    $('#confirm').show();
    alert('df');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you referenced the jQuery library? Are you getting any javascript console errors? Is the postback occurring before the javascript fires?

Comment: [This  Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056627/popupextender-on-imagebutton-inside-gridview-problem/4056689#4056689) of mine might be able to help. It is using ASP.net ajax  extensions but the principle is the same. There are also links to more comprehinsive tutorials.

Comment: @sam any error in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call, `alert('df')`, thread will be blocked until you click the "Ok" button of the alert then the postback will happen followed by.

But when you show the modal dialog only (without `alert`), it won't block the thread and hence postback will happen immediately.

Hence your modal dialogue will be disappeared after postback.

When you add `return false' as below, it will stop the postback.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDeletes" ToolTip="Delete" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" OnClick="btnDelete_Click1" OnClientClick="test();return false;" CssClass="GridDeletebtn" runat="server" />
```

Script

```
<script>
   function test()
            {
                $('#confirm').modal('show');
                //alert('df');
            }
        </script>
```

Html

```
<div id="confirm" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-body">
    Are you sure?
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" id="delete">Delete</button>
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sir, im calling alert , test for this,,im try o this but not show the modal popup

Comment: sir, im try that's work, but not showing popup , im click the button after display black screen, i think (.hide) is a problem

Comment: One of your css might be wrong, Chec this working fiddle, `http://jsfiddle.net/balasuar/h3WDq/1705/`

Comment: Sir ,Thanks for the help

Comment: @SamD May I know, why you unaccepted my answer? I actually resolved your underlying issue which you forgot it seems. The one you accepted simply has `$('.modal').show();` which is equivalent to `$('#confirm').modal('show');` in my answer. The issue you had is because of what has been explained in my answer.

Comment: sorry for the my mistake,thats is my fault  i was up vote wrong question in  i asked,

Answer (score 0):

If you can share a URL that I can test. Then  I will try it.
Moreover try to catch class name instead of id.
some thing like below.

$('.modal').show();

Comment: Sir, its not working, can you please explain about it

Comment: send me your URL. Then I will try to debug it from my browser and send you exactly working code.

Answer (score 0):

if you using gridview or repeater then call modal popup by below code
its working for me

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Remark_Modal<%# Eval("PrimaryID")%>">
    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>&nbsp;Details
</a>

<!--Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id='Remark_Modal<%# Eval("PrimaryID")%>' role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content card-blue-fill">
            <div class="modal-header card-header">
                <button type="button" class="modal-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <i class="fa fa-2x fa-close"></i>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i>&nbsp; <%# Eval("MissionName")%></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body card-block">
                <%# Eval("Remark")%>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use a ScriptManager tag at the beginning of your modal, else your ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript would not work. Below is the workaround that I use.**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upModal" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title"><asp:Label ID="errorMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Code-behind

```
private void showModal(string error)
        {
            message.Text = error;
            upModal.Update();
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "myModal", "$(document).ready(function () {$('#myModal').modal();});", true);
        }
```

Call the above showModal() function with appropriate message. You may have to add modal header & modal footer if needed.